# Как заблокировать создание файла?

Tags: c++, windows, драйвер

Нужно написать драйвер блокировать создание файла, пробую через Minifilter, но ничего. Получается видеть только мониторинг процессов (создание, удаление, изменение) Может кто нибудь сталкивался. Спасибо.
https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/filesys/miniFilter/minispy

Почитал в различных статьях, что требуется изменить входящий/исходящий вызов в этом участке кода.

```
CONST FLT_OPERATION_REGISTRATION Callbacks[] = {
{ IRP_MJ_CREATE,
  0,
  SpyPreOperationCallback,
  SpyPostOperationCallback },
 { IRP_MJ_OPERATION_END } };
```

вот код SpyPreOperationCallback, на одном из форумов прочитал что нужно сделать "Чтобы заблокировать доступ к файлу в pre-callback на IRP_MJ_CREATE, нужно
прописать в pData->IoStatus.Status подходящий код, например STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED, а
затем вернуть из функции FLT_PREOP_SUCCESS_NO_CALLBACK (или FLT_PREOP_COMPLETE,
если у тебя нет post-callback-а)." пробовал подставить, но ничего не происходит.

```
FLT_PREOP_CALLBACK_STATUS
#pragma warning(suppress: 6262) // higher than usual stack usage is considered safe in this case
SpyPreOperationCallback(
_Inout_ PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA Data,
_In_ PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects,
_Flt_CompletionContext_Outptr_ PVOID *CompletionContext)

{ FLT_PREOP_CALLBACK_STATUS returnStatus = FLT_PREOP_SUCCESS_NO_CALLBACK; //assume we are NOT going to call our completion routine
PRECORD_LIST recordList;

NTSTATUS nameStatus = STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
NTSTATUS targetNameStatus = STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;

PFLT_FILE_NAME_INFORMATION nameInfo = NULL;
PFLT_FILE_NAME_INFORMATION targetNameInfo = NULL;

if (MiniFSWatcherData.ClientPort == NULL || MiniFSWatcherData.WatchPath.Buffer == NULL)
{
    return FLT_PREOP_SUCCESS_NO_CALLBACK;
}

if (!FlagOn(Data->Flags, FLTFL_CALLBACK_DATA_IRP_OPERATION))
{
    return FLT_PREOP_SUCCESS_NO_CALLBACK;
}

if (FltObjects->FileObject == NULL || FltObjects->FileObject->FileName.Buffer == NULL || FltObjects->FileObject->DeviceObject == NULL)
{
    return FLT_PREOP_SUCCESS_NO_CALLBACK;
}

CONTINUE_IF_MATCHES(MiniFSWatcherData.WatchProcess, PsGetCurrentProcessId());

CONTINUE_IF_MATCHES(MiniFSWatcherData.WatchThread, PsGetCurrentThreadId());

if (Data->Iopb->MajorFunction == IRP_MJ_SET_INFORMATION && Data->Iopb->Parameters.SetFileInformation.FileInformationClass == FileRenameInformation)
{
    PFILE_RENAME_INFORMATION info = (PFILE_RENAME_INFORMATION)Data->Iopb->Parameters.SetFileInformation.InfoBuffer;
    if (info != NULL)
    {
        targetNameStatus = FltGetDestinationFileNameInformation(FltObjects->Instance, FltObjects->FileObject, info->RootDirectory, info->FileName, info->FileNameLength, FLT_FILE_NAME_NORMALIZED | MiniFSWatcherData.NameQueryMethod, &targetNameInfo);
    }
}

nameStatus = FltGetFileNameInformation(Data, FLT_FILE_NAME_NORMALIZED | MiniFSWatcherData.NameQueryMethod, &nameInfo);

if ((NT_SUCCESS(nameStatus) && SpyIsWatchedPath(&nameInfo->Name))
    || (NT_SUCCESS(targetNameStatus) && SpyIsWatchedPath(&targetNameInfo->Name)))
{
    recordList = SpyNewRecord();

    if (recordList) 
    {
        USHORT offset = SpyAddRecordName(&recordList->LogRecord, &nameInfo->Name, 0);
        if (NT_SUCCESS(targetNameStatus) && targetNameInfo != NULL)
        {
            SpyAddRecordName(&recordList->LogRecord, &targetNameInfo->Name, offset);
        }

        SpyLogPreOperationData(recordList);

        *CompletionContext = recordList;
        returnStatus = FLT_PREOP_SUCCESS_WITH_CALLBACK;
    }
}

if (nameInfo != NULL)
{
    FltReleaseFileNameInformation(nameInfo);
}

if (targetNameInfo != NULL)
{
    FltReleaseFileNameInformation(targetNameInfo);
}

    return returnStatus;
 }
```

Comment: Как это понимать  (3 плюса и 3 заявки на закрытие)?.. Я за  незакрытие

Comment: Вопрос та интересный, но связан с тематикой, которая не является тематикой широкой аудитории. Вопрос драйверов интересен еденицами, но и требует хорошего понимания как работают драйвера. Я условно виду три пути 1) Перехват АПИ для каждого процесса 2) найти "калбек" куда можно вставить проверку создания. 3) перехватить сами драйвера файловых систем (ntfs.sys и т п).

Comment: @ARHovsepyan 3 плюса ставили одни люди, а 3 закрывашки - другие.

Comment: @nick_n_a,  очевидно, меня удивляет такое сильное расхождение мнений

Comment: Ну тут нужно прочитать про типы драйвером на msdn. Выбрать подходящий и попробовать что-то сделать. Ну и разные хаки по замене драйвером, апи, хуки и тд.

Comment: Вас именно Windows интересует?

Comment: Да, Windows, но кажется для любой ОС это одинаково

Comment: @koly86 Сформулируйте вопрос нормально, сейчас даже при желании вам трудно помочь. Вопрос можно править, смотрите там под ним ссылка "править" есть.

Comment: Драйвера - они не одинаковы. Для линукса свои, для винды свои и т д. Мало того, драйвер для win98 не подходит не xp не 10-ке.

Comment: Понятно, необходимо для Windows 10

Comment: из последнего что нашел есть группы загрузки драйверов. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/load-order-groups-for-file-system-filter-drivers . FSFilter Security Enhancer

В эту группу входят драйверы фильтров, которые применяют блокировки и расширенные списки контроля доступа (ACL).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Короче говоря, каждый вид открытия или создания файла заканчивается в
IRP_MJ_CREATE обратный вызов. Вы можете получить имя файла, который будет открыт (или
создан) и имя папки и тому подобное (FltGetFileNameInformation)
и решить, разрешить ли запрос
(возврат FLT_PREOP_SUCCESS_NO_CALLBACK, который позволяет продолжить запрос)
или установите IoStatus в что-то вроде STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED и вернитесь
FLT_PREOP_COMPLETE, чтобы заблокировать запрос. Это, в двух словах, что ваши
фильтр должен сделать, чтобы заблокировать создание файлов в определенной папке.

Comment: Поставьте себе уже зеленую галочку, если вопрос отвечен.